# MVC 4 @HTML.DropdownlistFor onchange event needs to send SelectedIndex value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 4 and have an @HTML.DropdownlistFor() which loads the rest of the page based on it's selection. On change of the listbox, I want to reload the page so that it load the correct data. As well there are two other parameters that are needed to load the page correctly.

**In Create.cshtml view**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedMissionID,    Model.MissionsToDisplay, new { onchange = "ReloadPage();" })

function ReloadPage() {
  window.location = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CreateEdit", "DailyLog", new { ID = 1, ID2 = 0, dailyLogDate = Model.LogDate }))';

}
```

Where it says ID = 1, I want the selected index of the DropdownlistFor(SelectedMissionID), how do I get this?

I'm not sure if this is the best way to go to the controller, or if I should use a JQUERY .ajax post, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems something ideal for an ajax post.
What you have done is OK, inside the ReloadPage() function, just get the selected value in the DropDown, do the Ajax call passing the parameters, and in the success callback put your returned HTML in some container.

The idea is that you replace a part of your view with the return of your Ajax call, not all the page.

To get the selected value, using jQuery:

```
var selectedValue = $("select[name='SelectedMissionID']").val();
```

And that can be placed in your ReloadPage() function.

```
    $.post( "your action URL", { ID: selectedValue, OtherParam: "xxxxx" })
      .done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
//here you need to get the HTML, and put in a container
      });
```

Comment: i can get the selected value like that, but how do you put it in the parameter list? Thanks!

Comment: It was better to use the ajax post to send the values, that works well.